# Make container widget fill parent vertically

Tags: flutter

TL;DR Need the container to fill the vertical space so that it can act as a ontap listener. Have tried most solutions but nothing seems to work.

So what I am trying to do is to make my container fill up the vertical space while still having a fixed width. [Two first is what I have and third is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8oMB.png). The idea is to have the container transparent with a gesture ontap listener. If anyone have a better idea as for a different solution, feel free to suggest.

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: _move,
      onHorizontalDragEnd: _handleDragEnd,
      child: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Positioned.fill(           
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Container(
                  child: new IconButton(                          
                    padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 16.0, left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                    icon: new Icon(Icons.warning),
                    color: Colors.black12,
                    onPressed: () {},
                  )
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          new SlideTransition(
            position: new Tween<Offset>(
              begin:  Offset(0.0, 0.0),
              end: const Offset(-0.6, 0.0),
            ).animate(_animation),
            child: new Card(
              child: new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Container(
                    width: 20.0,
                    height: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.amber,
                  ),
                  new Expanded(
                    child: new Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        
                        _getListTile(),
                        _ifStoplineIsToBeShown()
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
```

I am quite sure that i have been missing something considering the fact that I have tried a lot of different things and nothing seems to work.

I have also uploaded an image with the debug painting [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uldtr.png).

PS. I know I have set the height to a fixed value, but this is the only way to show the container.

Comment: Is `onHorizontalDragStart` not being called? And where do you have your &quot;fixed width&quot;?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

The trick is to combine an `IntrinsicHeight` widget and a `Row` with `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`

This force the children of Row to expand vertically, but Row will take the least amount of vertical space possible.

```
Card(
  child: IntrinsicHeight(
    child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: 20.0,
          color: Colors.amber,
        ),
        // Expanded(...)
      ],
    ),
  )
)
```

Comment: Should it be mentioned that IntrinsicHeight has performance implications? https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html

Comment: I don't think so. The warning is here mostly to warn you against using it when a `ConstraintBox` is enough. This is the intended use case

Comment: Will try tomorrow, but this looks promising. Thanks all :)

Comment: This does not fill up the vertical space for me. What worked for me was setting the `Container.height` to `double.infinity`.

Comment: This seems to work https://stackoverflow.com/a/62358991/491950

Comment: W O W thought my problem wasn't solvable

Comment: FlutterError (BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.

Answer (score 131):

To stretch the container to full height of the parent use property `constraints:BoxConstraints.expand()` in container widget. Container occupy the complete space independent of the of child widget

```
Container(
  color: Colors.green,
  child: Text("Flutter"),
  constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
)
```

Please refer the link [Container Cheat sheet](https://medium.com/jlouage/container-de5b0d3ad184) for more about container

Comment: As this is more succinct, should this be used instead of the accepted answer?

Comment: perfect solution <3

Comment: Worked perfectly

Comment: Error : BoxConstraints forces an infinite width and infinite height.

Comment: @RajaC it does not work if container has a Singlechildscrollview() as parent.

Comment: Are you sure this gives better performance than the accepted answer?

Comment: @Kamlesh Yup, I also tried & this way not work if Container has SingleChildScrollView() as parent

Answer (score 43):

**Simply pass in: `double.infinity`.**

If you want a Container to fill all available space, you can just pass in:

```
width: double.infinity,
height: double.infinity
```

**Explanation:**

In Flutter, a child widget cannot exceed the "layout constraints" imposed by its parent widget. During the layout phase, Flutter engine uses a constraint solver to automatically correct "out-of-bound" values into what's allowed by its parent constraints.

For example, if you have a Container that's 50x50, and for its child, you pass in another Container that's 300x300, the inner container will be automatically corrected to "not exceed its parent", thus 50x50. Therefore, using sufficiently large values would always make sure you "fill parent".

In fact, even `BoxConstraints.expand()` exploits the same idea internally. If you open up the source code of `expand()`, you will see:

```
  /// Creates box constraints that expand to fill another box constraints.
  ///
  /// If width or height is given, the constraints will require exactly the
  /// given value in the given dimension.
  const BoxConstraints.expand({
    double width,
    double height,
  }) : minWidth = width ?? double.infinity,
       maxWidth = width ?? double.infinity,
       minHeight = height ?? double.infinity,
       maxHeight = height ?? double.infinity;
```

So if you are absolutely certain you want to fill all spaces, you can intuitively pass in a number bigger than the parent (or larger than the whole screen), like `double.infinity`.

Comment: Internal flutter changes to that logic have a bigger chance of breaking your code if you just mimic what Flutter does under the hood. Better practice is to use `constraints: BoxConstraints.expand()`.

Comment: @andreyrk Thanks! While your statement is generally correct, there is however no risk here. Flutter engine uses constraint solver to force bigger values into what's allowed by its parent, and that's one of the most fundamental principles behind how Flutter layout works. `BoxConstraints.expand()` merely exploits the same fact. I've updated my answer in an attempt to explain it better. If you're unfamiliar with these topics, you might want to look into how Flutter engine performs layout under the hood.

Comment: This is the way to go.  Simple to read and understand, without adding another widget to the tree (at least in the code you see).

Comment: upvote for the explanation, ty

Comment: it does not work `flutter: BoxConstraints forces an infinite width and infinite height.
flutter: These invalid constraints were provided to RenderDecoratedBox's layout() function by the following
flutter: function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:`

Answer (score 35):

As of Jan 2020 the simplest is to use an Expanded Widget

```
Expanded(flex: 1,
         child: Container(..),
            ),
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Comment: Hey, I've been trying this approach doesn't seem to work. Can you help ? The widget just vanishes if I don't set a height of the container inside it.

Comment: no need to set `flex: 1` since it's the value by default

Comment: This worked for me when I was trying to expand a container inside a card widget with a column. I have a material button inside a container at the end of the card that I wanted to center in the remaining portion of the card. Didn't give the infinity problem. Thanks!

Comment: this doesn't work for me.  
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.

Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a IntrinsicHeight widget.

Answer (score 8):

There are many answers which suggest using two things

1. constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
2. height: double.infinity,

But both these answer will give you an error like

> BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.

We can avoid these by calculating the height of the screen like

1. App Bar
2. Top Bar Space(Exist on the above App Bar)
3. Remaining screen

**1. Get the MediaQuery**

```
 final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
```

**2. Declare the AppBar Widget and same App Bar instance should be used in Scaffold App Bar**

```
final PreferredSizeWidget appBar = AppBar(
      title: Text('Home'),
    );
```

**3. Use calculated height**

```
      Container(
              width: mediaQuery.size.width,
              height: (mediaQuery.size.height -
                  appBar.preferredSize.height -
                  mediaQuery.padding.top),
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Set the height or width of a container to **double.maxFinite**

```
Container(
   height: double.maxFinite,
    width: 100,)
```

You can make your widget take the full size of a Container widget, and then set the container's height and/or width to **double.maxFinite**. This will make the Container take the height and/or width or its parent widget

Answer (score 2):

I propose using Expanded widget (which allows us to avoid IntrinsicHeight widget), combine it with the Container's alignment property and therefore make it work properly even if the Container is not the only one at the screen.

```
Expanded(
  child: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Text('Your text', textAlign: TextAlign.center))),
```

That way one also avoids potential app's crash which occurs often when you accidentally expand to infinity some parts of the widget tree both horizontally and vertically (that is why you are not able to use BoxConstraints widget in many cases).

One can read more about the problems of passing constraints in Flutter here - a must read: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-the-advanced-layout-rule-even-beginners-must-know-edc9516d1a2

Answer (score 1):

This work works for me

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
```