# Fill ListView tiles vertically by a container - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have been trying to put a line indicator on the left most margin of the card in my flutter app. I've tried a lot of things but didn't work.

There's an exact question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51155208/make-container-widget-fill-parent-vertically), which is actually the same issue I've been trying to solve.

The problem with the accepted solution is that it restricts the height of the hardcoded value, which I don't want. Rather the color should automatically fill the height of the card.

The Problem

[image]

I've tried all the three solutions and none of them fit my use case.

Output from [first solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51157072/11857690)
Here I've to hardcode the value to something larger so that all the text being displayed lies well inside it. That's something I feel is not a solution.

```dart
Card(
            key: ObjectKey(noteList[index]),
            elevation: 2.0,
            child: IntrinsicHeight(
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 4,
                    color: Color(noteList[index].intcolor),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 100,
                    child: ListTile(
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ SNIP ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[chip goes outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLwts.png)

Output from [Second solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57805016/11857690)
This doesn't show anything at all.

```dart
Card(
            key: ObjectKey(noteList[index]),
            elevation: 2.0,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
                    color: Color(noteList[index].intcolor),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 100,
                  child: ListTile(
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ SNIP ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[No output at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwYGq.png)

Output from [last solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59772282/11857690)
There's no color from the container.
[There's no color from the container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALx4Q.png)

Thanks a lot.

### Update 1  ( Monday, 6 April 2020 8:16 pm GMT )

Added code and repo for easy replication.

[Repo](https://github.com/ta1bbty/test_flutter)

`main.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  List<String> notes = [
    "fluttermaster.com",
    "Update Android Studio to 3.3",
    "Something long Something long Something long Something long Something long Something long",
  ];

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Simple Note ListView"),
      ),
      body: Container(
          color: Colors.white10,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: HomePage(notes)),
    ),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> notes;

  HomePage(this.notes);
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: notes.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, pos) {
        return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 2.0,
              child: Row(
                // key: _cardKey,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Container(
                      // -------------------- This here ----------------------------------------------
                      // FixMe : This shouldn't be hardcoded, rather it should fill the height of it's parent element, in this case card
                      // https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-widget-size-and-position-b0a9ffed9407
                      height: 71,
                      color: Colors.green,
                      // -------------------- This here ----------------------------------------------
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 100,
                    child: ListTile(
                      // For center alignment from vertical and horizontal : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51546279
                      // Since using CircleAvatar does this but it decreases size of icon too : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16061
                      leading: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.receipt),
                        ],
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                        notes[pos],
                      ),
                      subtitle: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(notes[pos].substring(0, 10)),
                          // What is the best way to optionally include a widget in a list of children
                          // https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3783#issuecomment-506019822
                          if ((pos % 2) == 0)
                            Chip(
                              avatar: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
                                child: Icon(Icons.timer),
                              ),
                              label: Text('2FA'),
                            ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      trailing: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Wrap(
                            spacing: 10,
                            direction: Axis.vertical,
                            alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.check,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {},
                              )
                            ]),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Done. https://github.com/ta1bbty/test_flutter/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps one way of doing it is to use Stack

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: notes.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, pos) {
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Card(
                margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(Icons.receipt),
                    ],
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    notes[pos],
                  ),
                  subtitle: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(notes[pos].substring(0, 10)),
                      if ((pos % 2) == 0)
                        Chip(
                          avatar: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade800,
                            child: Icon(Icons.timer),
                          ),
                          label: Text('2FA'),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  trailing: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Wrap(
                        spacing: 10,
                        direction: Axis.vertical,
                        alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.check,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {},
                          )
                        ]),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                child: Container(
                  width: 5,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    )
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Another working solution I got was : https://www.reddit.com/r/Flutter/comments/fwdphy/fill_the_parent_widget_vertically_by_a_container/fmo3f16?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x