# Flutter : Row -> Expanded -> Container : All containers to have same height dynamically

Tags: flutter, dart

```
return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {

              },
              child: Text(
                    "Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 5),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(            
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            child: InkWell( // tried raisedbutton - height is not fully covered
              onTap: () {

              },
              child: Text(
                "blah blah blah",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

[image]

Because i am using `expanded` widget in `row`, I am not able to use `Container( height: double.infinity..`

The two boxes are given equal space with the help of `expanded` now i need two buttons with same dynamic height. Because text length will vary.

Comment: Try adding `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,` to the `Row`

Comment: `Another exception was thrown: BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.` - i got the following error after adding `crossAxisAlignment`

Comment: created a small sample on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/16YUsPGB)

Comment: I just tried that coding in dartpad. Left side widget is clickable everywhere. But right side, only the text is clickable

Comment: Made Changes [new pastebin](https://pastebin.com/6AKs5QwA)  Replaced `InkWell` with `RaisedButton` and removed `alignment`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/vb2C0G3Z This is how i actually implemented. The `Row` is a one of the child of a `Column` I am getting `Another exception was thrown: BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.` Without Column it works as expected

Answer (score 4):

Someone already answered this at: [Flutter Layout Row / Column - share width, expand height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326170/flutter-layout-row-column-share-width-expand-height)

You could try adding **IntrinsicHeight** as parent to the Row, and add **constraints: BoxConstraints.expand()** to the Container:

```
return IntrinsicHeight( 
    child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {

              },
              child: Text(
                    "Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 5),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            child: InkWell( // tried raisedbutton - height is not fully covered
              onTap: () {

              },
              child: Text(
                "blah blah blah",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapped each `Conatiner` in the `Column` with `Expanded`. 
`Expanded` will allocate the available space among each of the childern of `Column`.
Removed the height from the first `Container`

The code which has been modified [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/d5rjq3ib)

Hope this helps.